# OAuth2/OIDC Which flow should I use

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have an OIDC server setup for authentication and authorization. And I also have a desktop application which is essentially a browser with some extra functions.

The application makes calls to a API server directly and the embedded browser visits a web application that also makes requests to the same API server. Everytime the application is executed, user is required to login once.

Should I use hybrid flow? Can the tokens be shared between the app and web app?

I would also like to know how does the Facebook mobile app do authentication with its native part and web view part.

Edit: the web application is a server side MVC application

Answer (score 1):

If the web application is an SPA, and thus a [public client](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1), then you can simply use the implicit grant type and pass the access and ID tokens from the embedded browser to the native application.

But assuming the web application is a server side application and thus a confidential client, then you would most likely want to use the authorization_code flow as the basis, since it will give you access to a refresh_token if needed on the server and you can rely on the Authorization Provider's TLS certificate for trust.

You can now choose whether to render back the access token from the server to the frontend, or to use a hybrid flow as you say. The latter would allow you to already pass the ID Token and access token to the native application without waiting for the backend call to the token endpoint and the page refresh to complete.

However, when processing tokens client side you [must verify the ID Token signature](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitIDTValidation) and [match the access token to it via `at_hash`](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitTokenValidation) since you can't rely on the TLS certificate of the token endpoint in that case.

Comment: Do they have to use the same client_id if using hybrid flow?

Comment: The hybrid flow uses a single client ID for both components of your app indeed.